# Python generator that returns the same thing forever

Tags: python, generator

I'm looking for a standard function that does this:

```
def Forever(v):
  while True:
    yield v
```

It seems so trivial I can't believe there isn't a standard version.

For that matter anyone know of a good link to a list of all the standard generator functions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`itertools.repeat(x[, count])` repeats x a finite number of times if told how many times, otherwise repeats forever.

For a general list of all of the itertools generator functions, see here:

http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 10):

Your are looking for [`itertools.repeat(object[, times])`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

> Make an iterator that returns `object` over and over again. Runs indefinitely unless the `times` argument is specified.